# Finding Facebook Friends on app, and not on app

Tags: python, django, hash-map, facebook

This code gets all of a user's Facebook friends who use our app and returns a dictionary with keys that are their id's in our database and values that are a default connection level.

The code should also return all of the users Facebook friends who aren't using our app.

I made `fb_id_on_app` a dictionary of keys that are `facebook_id`s so that I could take advantage of the \$O(1)\$ lookup time for dictionaries. If I had made it a list it would have been an \$O(n)\$ where \$n\$ is the size of the list to check if the value was in there.

I'm sure there is a better way to do this any ideas. We are using Django framework as well.

```
DEFAULT_CONNECTION_LEVEL = 10
# Up to a whole day
UPDATE_FRIENDS_EVERY_N_MINUTES = 360


def find_friends_on_app(friends):
    """
    Checks each facebook id to find which facebook friends
    use our app
    """
    facebook_ids = [friend["id"] for friend in friends]
    dt_friends = User.objects.filter(
        facebook_id__in=facebook_ids)
    friends_on_app = {friend.id: DEFAULT_CONNECTION_LEVEL for friend in
                  dt_friends}
    fb_id_on_app = {friend.facebook_id: "value" for friend in
                dt_friends}
    friends_not_on_app = \
        [{'Name': friend.get("name"),
          'id': friend.get("id")} for friend in friends if
         fb_id_on_app.get(friend.get("id")) is None]
    return friends_not_on_app, friends_on_app
```

Comment: How are you calling this function, what exactly is `friends` parameter? Could you include the definition of your user object too?